# How to load more pages on clicking the button

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, api

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const Url = "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/episode/"

function Episodes() {
const [wholeData, setWholeData] = useState({})
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(Url).then(res => {
        setWholeData(res.data)
    })
}, [])

const { info, results: defaultR = [] } = wholeData;
const [results, setResults] = useState(defaultR)
const [page, setPage] = useState({
    ...info,
    current: Url
})
const {current} = page

useEffect(() =>{
    if(current === Url) return;

    const request = () =>{
        axios.get(current).then(res => {
            const nextData = res.json();

            setPage({
                current,
                ...nextData.info
            });

            if (!nextData.info?.prev){
                setResults(nextData.results);
                return;
            }

            setResults(prev => {
                return [...prev, ...nextData.results]
            });  })
    }
    request();
}, [current])

const handleLoadMore = () =>{
    setPage(prev => {
        return{
            ...prev,
            current:page?.next
        }
    })
}
}


return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <form /* onSubmit={searchEpisode}*/>
                    <input className="form-control mt-4" type="text"
                        placeholder="Name of the Episode.." aria-label="Search" style={{ width: "50%", margin: "auto" }} /*onChange={searchIt} */ />
                </form>
            </div>
            <div className="row mx-auto text-light">
                {
                    results.map(item => {
                        return (
                            <div key={item.id} className="col-md-3">
                                <div className="card mt-3 mb-2 mx-auto" style={{ width: "18rem" }}>
                                    <div className="card-body">
                                        <h5 className="card-title text-dark">{item.id}. {item.name}</h5>
                                        <h6 className="card-subtitle mb-3 text-muted">{item.episode}</h6>
                                        <li href="#" className="text-muted">{item.air_date}</li>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                    )}
            </div >
            <button onClick={handleLoadMore}>LoadMore</button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Episodes
```

I need to render the 41 episodes of Rick and Morty in a page as the default first 20 episodes will be rendered and on clicking the button, I need to render the rest of the episode using the API which is in the info property. But I'm getting an error like this

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined

Comment: When sharing a stack trace, can you (1) share the _full_ stack trace - not just the first line - so we know where the error came from. And (2) put it in a code block, to get monospace formatting?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried googling your stack trace? I found https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/632 as the first result on google - this leads me to suspect maybe Url isn't populated? But you'll have to debug to check.

In general, I think this is a good candidate to create a minimal repro for. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Start from scratch, or keep stripping stuff away. If you can remove the amount of code, you remove the search space for potential bugs. That should guide you to the answer :)

Comment: @Mark. Sure I will put the whole code.

Comment: This file doesn't call the `protocol` property anywhere.  Let's have a look at that code.